# Oracle check regexp if a condition is satisfied

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, constraints

I want to add a constraint to a table in my Oracle server.

How could I do to check a phone number is 10 numbers (not letters) if a user inserts a citizen from Finland?

This is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE CITIZEN ADD CONSTRAINT checkPhone
CHECK (CASE Country  WHEN  'Finland'  THEN REGEXP_LIKE(Phone,'^[0-9]{10}$') END );
```

But I get the following error:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: From Technet, `The Oracle REGEXP_LIKE condition allows you to perform regular expression matching in the WHERE clause of a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.`http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php

Comment: ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167767/check-constraint-of-string-to-contain-only-digits-oracle-sql or perhaps `LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(phone, ' +-.0123456789',' '))) is null`

Comment: Similar question about check constraint containing case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072463/oracle-sql-can-case-be-used-in-a-check-constraint-to-determine-data-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite condition in proper way

```
ALTER TABLE CITIZEN ADD CONSTRAINT checkPhone
CHECK (( Country  ='Finland' and REGEXP_LIKE(Phone,'^[0-9]{10}$')) or (Country!='Finland' or Country is null));
```

Comment: If I write that constraint, and I insert 112233445A, says that comma is missing. Why?

Comment: could you please show your exact error message? it works for me on 12c, SQL> insert into citizen values ('Finland', '112233445A');
insert into citizen values ('Finland', '112233445A')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (C##MINA.CHECKPHONE) violated

Answer (score 0):

A check constraint needs to resolve to a boolean expression and a case resolves to a value so you need to compare it to something.  So if you are deadset on using case then it has to do a comparison.  Or update it to not use a case like @mina wrote:

Set up our test data

```
create table citizen (
  id number,
  country varchar2(100),
  phone varchar2(10)
);

Table created.

insert into citizen values (10, 'Finland', '1234567890');
insert into citizen values (20, 'Ireland', 'abcdefghij');
```

Try to add our check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE CITIZEN ADD CONSTRAINT checkPhone
  CHECK (CASE Country  WHEN  'Finland'  THEN REGEXP_LIKE(Phone,'^[0-9]{10}$') END );
                                                                                *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

But if we modify it to do a comparison:

```
ALTER TABLE CITIZEN ADD CONSTRAINT checkPhone
CHECK (case when country = 'Finland' and not REGEXP_LIKE(Phone,'^[0-9]{10}$') then 0 else 1 END);

Table altered.
```

Then we can test it:

```
insert into citizen values (10, 'Finland', '123456789z');

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (CHECKPHONE) violated

insert into citizen values (100, 'Finland', '1234567890');
1 row created.
```

Comment: @v8rs please post your updated constraint definition and the error you get.  I do not have access to a 10g instance but I don't see any features related to this that were added in 11.